# For each group in Pandas dataframe, return the most common value if it shows up more than `x%` of the time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given a pandas dataframe, I would like to return a column's (string datatype) most common value for each groupby if this value shows up in more than `n%` of the rows, otherwise return 'NA'.

Comment: Can you create some data sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need test number of most common values by count:

```
N = 5
def f(x):
    y = x.value_counts()
    return y.index[0] if y.iat[0] > N else np.nan


df = df.groupby('g')['col'].agg(f).reset_index(name='new')
```

Or by percentages:

```
n = 50
def f(x):
    y = x.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
    return y.index[0] if y.iat[0] > n else np.nan


df = df.groupby('g')['col'].agg(f).reset_index(name='new')
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `value_counts`, then `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('AAAAAABBBBBB'), 'value': list('aabbcdeeeeff')})

thresh = 3
out = (df[['group', 'value']].value_counts()
       .loc[lambda x: x>thresh]
       .groupby(level='group').idxmax().tolist()
       )
```

Example output:

```
[('B', 'e')]
```

With percentages:

```
thresh = 30
out = (df[['group', 'value']].value_counts()
       .loc[lambda x: x>thresh/100]
       .groupby(level='group').idxmax().tolist()
       )
```

output:

```
[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'e')]
```